# Firebase firestore null document path

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am unable to start an activity due to having a `null` document path from the firestore database. I don't know what's wrong, your help means alot.

Below is the code:-

```
DocumentReference documentReference2 = fStore.collection("users").document(userID)
                .collection("Values").document("DabaCount");
        documentReference2.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                num = String.valueOf(value.getString("Count"));
            }
        });

        int numnum = Integer.parseInt(num);

        int ii = 1;

        if (numnum > ii){
            ii = 1;
        }

        String ci = String.valueOf(ii);
        String DabaPattern = "Daba" + ci;

        DocumentReference documentReference3 = fStore.collection("users").document(userID)
                .collection("DabaSet").document(DabaPattern);
        documentReference3.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                DabaKey = String.valueOf(value.getString("DabaID"));
            }
        });

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(DabaKey);
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Weight = value;
                Toast.makeText(GetDaba.this, Weight, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {}
        });
```

Here is the output error:-

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.smartdaba, PID: 6733
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.smartdaba/com.example.smartdaba.GetDaba}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be null.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be null.
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:147)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.document(CollectionReference.java:103)
        at com.example.smartdaba.GetDaba.onCreate(GetDaba.java:75)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: What's the value of `userID` in your reference?

Answer (score -1):

1. Seems you are trying to access data from an empty `document` from your
   code. Please, make sure in the `firebase firestore` you have
   collections' or documents' names corresponding to the ones written
   in your code.
2. From your code above, you have declared a collection reference
   variable but you are missing a `get()` method which is used to
   retrieve the information from the cloud firestore. Here is an
   example:-

wrong way to retrieve information from the cloud
firestore,

```
            documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                    //Firebase data manipulation
                }
            });
```

correct way to retrieve information from the cloud firestore,

```
        documentReference.get().addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                //Firebase data manipulation
            }
        });
```

Try to make sure you don't miss the `get()` method when getting data
from the cloud firestore.

Comment: Your statement in incorrect.  A document snapshot is attached to a documentReference.  No need to fetch the document; in fact, the result of a get() does not HAVE a snapshot method.